# SharePoint OAuth Write Scope

Tags: c#, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, sharepoint-2013, office365

When I put Write scope in the Authorization flow, the service only give me Read permission.
How can I have the service ask for Write permission too?
I am trying to get access token using C# (VS 2013) for updating file in the SharePoint (Office 365), but it refuse to give me. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using low-trust ACS oauth or AAD-based oauth?